# creating tags during post creation works, but using existing ones don't - possible problem with serializer or something else

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to write a code that will make it able to create tags during creating post and use tags created by urself, other users earlier. I think thats a common approach. This test works without a problem, because it creates a tag during post creation:

> ```
>         class TagTests(TestCase):
>     """Tests for tags."""
>     def setUp(self):
>         self.client = APIClient()
>         self.user = User.objects.create_user(email='mail@example.com', password='password123')
>         self.client.force_authenticate(self.user)
>         self.admin = User.objects.create_superuser(email='admin@example.com', password='password123')
>         self.post = Post.objects.create(user=self.user, text='Test post')
>         self.tag1 = Tag.objects.create(user=self.user, name='Existing Tag 1')
>         self.tag2 = Tag.objects.create(user=self.user, name='Existing Tag 2')
>         self.url_post = reverse('posts-list')
>     def test_create_tags_during_post_creation(self):
>         """Test creating tags during post creation."""
>         payload = {'text': 'Test', 'tags': [{'name': 'tag1'}, {'name': 'tag2'}]}
>         res = self.client.post(self.url_post, payload, format='json')
>         post_id = res.data['id']
>         post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
>         tags = post.tags.all()
>         tag_names = set(tag.name for tag in tags)
>         
>         self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
>         self.assertIn('tag1', tag_names)
>         self.assertIn('tag2', tag_names)
> ```

However I cannot get my next test to work, because it returns error 400 and response is `{'tags': [{'name': [ErrorDetail(string='tag with this name already exists.', code='unique')]}, {'name': [ErrorDetail(string='tag with this name already exists.', code='unique')]}]}`

```
    def test_create_post_with_existing_tags(self):
        """Test creating post with existing tags."""
        payload = {'text': 'Test post creating with existing tags', 
                        'tags': [{'name': 'Existing Tag 1'},
                                        {'name': 'Existing Tag 2'}]}
        res = self.client.post(self.url_post, payload, format='json')
        print(res.data)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        post_id = res.data['id']
        post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        tags = post.tags.all()
        tag_names = set(tag.name for tag in tags)
        self.assertIn('Existing Tag 1', tag_names)
        self.assertIn('Existing Tag 2', tag_names)
```

Of course I instantly thought problem was inside my serializer and `create` method in `PostSerializer` (ive changed it multiple times, because i thought that `user=user` may result in some problems, but it wasn't it). I put some print statements at the beginning of the create class but I don't think my test even reached it. I think because of error 400 it does not go to create method in PostSerializer. I feel stuck and I don't know honestly how to repair it :) that's why I also overwritten validate_tags method, but it also is not a problem.

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'name']
        read_only_fields = ['id']

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for the Post object."""
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id', 'text', 'image', 'date_created', 'user', 'tags']
        read_only_fields = ['id', 'date_created', 'user']
    def validate_tags(self, tags):
        return tags
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        validated_data['user'] = user
        tags = validated_data.pop('tags', [])
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for tag_data in tags:
            tag_name = tag_data.get('name')
            tag, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_name, user=user)
            post.tags.add(tag)
        return post
```

Comment: Can you please add the error stacktrace? From which line error is thrown? I suspect it is thrown from setup where no `get_or_create` handler present. Is it not necessary to clean those tags in after hook?